# Java exception handling - Unexpected Output

Tags: java, exception

I have the following pieces of codes from Java - A Beginner's Guide (Schildt), Chapter 9.

```
package com.chapter.nine;

public class UseThrowableMethods {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            ExcTest.genException();
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException excp){
            System.out.println("Standard message is:");
            System.out.println(excp);
            System.out.println("\nStack Trace:");
            excp.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("After the catch statement");
    }
}


public class ExcTest {
    static void genException(){ 
        int nums[] = new int [4];
        System.out.println("Before an exception is generated");
        nums[7] = 10;
        System.out.println("This should not be displayed");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I expect the output displayed on the Console to be the same as in the Book (as well as inside a Debug Session), which is:

```
Before an exception is generated
Standard message is:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Stack Trace:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at com.chapter.nine.ExcTest.genException(ExcTest.java:11)
    at com.chapter.nine.UseThrowableMethods.main(UseThrowableMethods.java:12)
After the catch statement
```

However, when I run the code, the actual output displayed is as follows:

```
com.chapter.nine.UseThrowableMethods
Before an exception is generated
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
Standard message is:
    at com.chapter.nine.ExcTest.genException(ExcTest.java:11)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

    at com.chapter.nine.UseThrowableMethods.main(UseThrowableMethods.java:12)
Stack Trace:
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
After the catch statement
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What is going on?

Comment: The most obvious difference is that you are executing yours inside intellij, the one in the book is executed on the command line. The differences are not semantically important.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What I don't understand is difference in outputs when I run the code inside and outside the debugger. The run inside the debugger produces expected order of print statements, not otherwise? It is slightly confusing.

Comment: The `After the catch statement` line appears in the middle of the stack trace because it is written to stdout, whereas the stack trace is written to stderr. Those two streams aren't synchronized, so one can write to the terminal in the middle of the other's message.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I believe the concept of streams come up in the next chapter. Thanks for your quick reply though.

Comment: does changing `System.out.println` to `System.err.println`give you more like what you expect?

Comment: Yes! The output now looks more consistent with the book's example. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: OK. Your book might not actually mention about the fact that the stdout and stderr streams might interleave in your terminal, since it's quite hard to reproduce. If you need to, you can manually flush the streams using `System.out.flush()` or `System.err.flush()` as appropriate.